# How to check ContentType.Hidden using the CAML Query?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I want to filter from the CAML query to ListItem.ContentType.Hidden.

with SharePoint To Linq like this Code.

```
var query = from item in list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()) 
                where item.ContentType.Hidden == false select item;
```

If I check with pure CAML Query,Should I write code and how?

Is a simple question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot check the `Hidden` property in a pure CAML query. In CAML only the ContentType's name and the ID is available (Fields *ContentType* and *ContentTypeID*).

If there are only a few hidden content types that have to be excluded you could first load these hidden content types and exclude them in the CAML query:

Extract hidden content types:

```
SPWeb web = // ...
IEnumerable<string> contentTypeIds = web.AvailableContentTypes
  .Cast<SPContentType>()
  .Where(ct => ct.Hidden)
  .Select(ct => ct.Id.ToString());
```

CAML query:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Neq>
      <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeID'/>
      <Value Type='Text'>[HiddenContentTypeId]</Value>
    </Neq>
    <Neq>
      <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeID'/>
      <Value Type='Text'>[AnotherHiddenContentTypeId]</Value>
    </Neq>
  </And>
  <!-- more hidden content types -->
</Where>
```

Comment: Hi,Mr.Stefan. Your explanation is simple and very straightforward to me.Thanks to your great advice.